# Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, activity

Создал проект в студии с готовым активити `Navigation Drawer`, после открытия проекта, когда добавляю новые активити на toobar-e нету кнопки которое вызывает Navigation Drawer (боковое меню присутствующие в приложении), как сделать так чтоб эта кнопка появилась во всех активити?

переопределив данный метод, получилось добавить кнопку меню, но боковое нет

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

и как изменить title активити, при переходе между активити в title название приложения, а нужно сделать так чтоб на каждом активити был свой title

Comment: Вам нужна просто кнопка меню как там или вы хотите полный функционал Navigation Drawer как в первом активити?

Comment: полный функционал

Comment: Я советую тогда использовать контейнер с фрагментами, или придется Navigation Drawer полностью копировать. По сути это будет выглядеть как эмулция одного и того же Navigation Drawer.

Comment: везде вместо активити фрагменты использовать?

Comment: Как так проще написать, внутри активити использовать фрагменты и делать переходы не из activity1 -> activity2 при нажатии на drawer, а будет выглядеть как activity1(fragment1) -> activity1(fragment2) и тд. А так как у вас drawer привязан к  activity1 то его не придется переиспользовать, и очень много бонусов ещё сверху

Comment: понял попробую сейчас, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Используйте вместо активити фрагменты. По умолчанию создается `layout` с именем `content_main.xml`. В нем и размещайте ваши фрагменты.